# Is any mention about Grama Devathas in Puranas and Tantras?

Tags: puranas, identification-request, tantra

In puranas and tantras, is there any information about Grama Devathas?

Answer (score 1):

The only instance I could find is in the [Skanda Purana, Book 2.4 chapter 35](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371677.html) which translates the word *grāmadevatā* to “rural deities”:

> Listen, O Viṣṇu, I shall grant you another boon. [...] After granting him boons thus Śiva vanished. Hence both Hari and Hara are to be worshipped with all efforts.
>
> In Kaliyuga Viṣṇu abandons the earth for (after?) ten thousand years, the waters of Gaṅgā for half that period **and the rural deities (*grāmadevatā*) for half of the latter**.

[Source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc750540.html) for the Sanskrit verse.

In the [Arthaśāstra book 3 chapter 10](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kautilya-arthashastra/d/doc366093.html), we find mention of “Bulls, let out in the name of the village deity (*grāmadevavṛṣa*)”:

> Bulls, let out in the name of the village deity (*grāmadevavṛṣa*), cows which have not passed ten days inside the enclosure after calving, or bulls or bullocks kept for crossing cows shall not be punished. [...]

Another related term *gṛhapradevatā* is mentioned together with *grāmadevatā* in a single verse in the [Lakṣmīnārāyaṇasaṃhitā](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lakshminarayana-samhita-sanskrit/d/doc513375.html) verse 1.160.186:

> ātṛṇastambaparyantāstathā gṛhapradevatāḥ |
> grāmadevā vanadevāḥ kṣetrapālāstathaiva ca || 186 ||

There is mention of *gṛhadevatā* (“deity of the house”) in the [Manthānabhairava-tantra](https://books.google.nl/books?id=2DhazgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) Kumārikākhaṇḍa chapter 42 verse 28cd-30, However, I advise to read the introduction first. There are also several mentions of *gṛhadevatā* in various Buddhist Tantras but that is beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you provide the name of Grama Devathas from Puranas/Tantras